# Using an awk variable in the string substitution portion of gsub

Tags: awk

I want to use a command line variable to replace text found with a regular expression.

Something like:

```
awk --lint=fatal -v awk_var=XYZ '{ gsub(/^ABCD=.*$/, "ABCD=<awk_var>"); print}'
```

Haven't been able to figure out what the `awk_var` syntax should be.

Comment: Please post samples of input and output in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not shown samples so based on your shown code and ask, could you please try following.

```
awk --lint=fatal -v awk_var=XYZ '{ gsub(/^ABCD=.*$/, "ABCD=" awk_var); print}'
```

You shouldn't give `"` with your variable else it will be considered as a text.

Comment: awk string concatenation: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Concatenation.html

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.